# How to download file using react "Link" tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to download the image using the URL.
this is what I am trying, but facing error **Failed - No file**.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Download from '../assets/download.png'

//More imports

export function Home(props) {
    const [image, setIamge] = useState([]);
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');

    //more states
   //More functions

    const handleDownload = (item) => {
        //item.url = "https://unsplash.com/photos/yC-Yzbqy7PY"
        setImageUrl(item.url)
    }
    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            {
                image.length ? image.map((item, key) => (
                    <div key={key} className="image-wrapper">
                        <Link className='download-link' to={imageUrl} target="_blank" download>
                            <img src={Download} onClick={() => { handleDownload(item) }} alt="fff" height="15px" width="15px" />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                )) : null}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

I wanted to download the image on click of the download icon.

Comment: You can use filesaver.js to download files easily. Please refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: please provive a sandbox in order to better help you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way and this is working fine for me.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Download from '../assets/download.png'

//More imports

export function Home(props) {
    const [image, setIamge] = useState([]);
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');

    //more states
   //More functions

    const handleDownload = (item) => {
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = item.url + "/download?force=true";
        a.download = 'image.png';
        a.click();
    }
    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            {
                image.length ? image.map((item, key) => (
                    <div key={key} className="image-wrapper">
                        <Link className='download-link' download>
                            <img src={Download} onClick={() => { handleDownload(item) }} alt="fff" height="15px" width="15px" />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                )) : null}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly open the link using like below and image will get downloaded. If you are framing your URL correctly, then you may try the below code for download

```
const handleDownload = (item) => {
        //item.url = ""https://unsplash.com/photos/yC-Yzbqy7PY""
          window.open(item.url, "_blank");
        setImageUrl(item.url)
    }
```

Comment: @Majid Did the solution help you?

Comment: No, solution didn't help me.